# Iterate dataframe and sum transactions by condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following sample of data:

```
    id   year  type  num
     1   1994   A     0
     2   1950   A  2333
     3   1977   B  4444
     4   1995   B   555
     1   1994   A     0
     6   1955   A   333
     7   2006   B  4123
     6   1975   A     0
     9   1999   B   123
     3   1950   A  1234
```

I'm looking for the easiest way how to sum column 'num' based on conditions of type == 'A' and year < 1999

I'm iterating through the dataframe df with the data:

```
    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df_sum = pd.DataFrame
    
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['type'] == 'A' and row['year'] < 1999:
            df_sum = df_sum.append(row) //This doesn't work
```

and trying to store the rows that match the conditions into df_sum where I'd make the sumarized num by id. Have no idea how to iterate and store the data based on condition into new dataframe.

The desired output would be:

```
id num_sum
1   0
2   2333
6   333
.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For summarised data you could filter, groupby sum then reset index

```
df_sum = df[((df.type=='A')&(df.year<1999))].groupby('id').sum('num').reset_index()
df_sum
Out[276]: 
   id  year   num
0   1  3988     0
1   2  1950  2333
2   3  1950  1234
3   6  3930   333
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`df.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) to accomplish that.

```py
filtered_df = df.query('type == "A" and year < 1999')
sum_df = filtered_df.groupby("id")["num"].sum().reset_index()
print(sum_df)
```

Output:

```
   id      num
0   1        0
1   2     2333
2   3     1234
3   6      333
```